# Spark REST Api with spark 2.1

Tags: apache-spark

We are trying to migrate from spark 1.6 to spark 2.1.
I have tried configuring spark master and worker locally, and found that spark REST api is not same as it is earlier.

With spark 1.6 when i started master, i used to get all the applications response using following url

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/applications

Now, with spark 2.1, i tried the same, but it is not as expected.

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/applications is just showing the web ui

Am i missing any configurations.?

Comment: Read the docs? That looks correct https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

Comment: I read the docs. and most importantly i was able to access the rest api with older version of spark in the same way.. You can try downloading the spark directly from spark home page and configure it immediately. Looks like something changed..

Comment: I have it installed already, I just haven't had the time to use Spark2

Comment: Ok, have you checked the rest api end point as per the documentation.?

Comment: It works as per the documentation with 1.6. Probably you can try with older version and see. It just takes download time + 2 minutes to start master and start slave. nothing much.

Comment: I encountered the same issue a couple of days ago and created a workaround using the `/json` url (that one works). I saw that you created a Jira ticket that got marked as resolved. Please update this question if you get it to work, or let me know if I can help get some traction to this problem

Comment: I did the same, using /json after master ui. But, our monitoring requirement needs more than that, and rest api response is key for our alerts. I will surely let you know, if i get any update.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of applications and their states, try: `http://localhost:8080/json`

You will get something like:

```
{
    url: "spark://...:7077",
    workers: [...],
    cores: 6,
    coresused: 0,
    memory: 19374,
    memoryused: 0,
    activeapps: [...],
    completedapps: [...],
    activedrivers: [...],
    status: "ALIVE"
}
```